# NASM Memory Addressing

Tags: assembly, nasm, memory-address

I am playing around with program command line arguments. In particular I am trying to do some testing on the string argv[1]. If I use a two step method of getting the address to argv[1], my code runs fine.

```
mov ebx, [ebp+12]
mov eax, [ebx+4] ; address of argv[1]
```

If I use one step, my program prints jibberish.

```
mov eax, [ebp+16] ; address of argv[1]
```

Am I incorrect in assuming that either method would now refer to the address [ebp+16]? Am I missing something trivial?

Comment: They are not the same. The first does `*(*(ebp+12)+4)` the second just `*(ebp+16)`. You can't leave out dereferencing.

Comment: Thanks @DanMašek for being facetiously unhelpful.

Comment: @Jester Much appreciated. I will think on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easy to get confused when working with pointers to pointers in assembly.

`argv` is an "array of strings" or better an array of pointers to char, since in C arrays decay into pointers to their item type when passed as arguments, in truth `argv` it is a pointer to pointer to char or `char** argv`.

This tells us that we need two dereferencing to access the chars of any of the strings and one to access any pointer to any of such strings.

Assuming the *cdecl* convention where parameters are passed on the stack in reverse order, and assuming a standard prolog that sets a standard frame-pointer we have that the value of `argc` is at `ebp+0ch`.
Note that `ebp` has the semantic of a pointer and so `ebp+0ch` is just pointer arithmetic to get another pointer, this time to the `argc` value.

If we were willing to give `ebp+0ch` a C type it would be `char***`, hence two dereferencing are needed to access the pointer `argv[1]`.

The code to get `argv[1]` into `ESI` is:

```
;typeof(ebp+0ch) = char***

mov esi, DWORD [ebp+0ch]      ;1st defer, esi = argv, typeof(esi) = char**
mov esi, DWORD [esi+04h]      ;2nd defer, esi = argv[1], typeof(esi) = char*

;Optional, Get a char
mov al, BYTE [esi]            ;3rd defer, al = argv[1][0], typeof(al) = char
```

The types check.

---

Sounds confusing?
Let's draw those pointers!

```
       The stack                                     The memory

100ch | 2000h  | argv                         2000h | 2008h   | argv[0]
1008h | 2      | argc                         2004h | 2010h   | argv[1]
1004h | yyyyyy | return address               2008h | file    | argv[0][0..3]
1000h | xxxxxx | old frame pointer            200ch | .a\0\0  | argv[0][4..7]
                                              2010h | -arg    | argv[1][0..3]
EBP = 1000h                                   2014h | 1\0\0\0 | argv[1][4..7]
```

`ebp+0ch` is 1000h + 0ch = 100ch and it is the address of the `argv` value.
`mov esi, DWORD [ebp+0ch]` is like `mov esi, DWORD [100ch]` and it sets `ESI` to 2000h.
2000h is the value of `argv` which is an array so it is the address of `argv[0]`.

The address of `argv[1]` is four bytes ahead, thus 2000h+04h = 2004h.
`mov esi, DWORD [esi+04h]` is like `mov esi, DWORD [2004h]` and it sets `ESI` to 2010h.
2010h is the address of the string "-arg1".

---

Note that the picture above is not C nor C++ standard compliant as `argv[argc]` must be 0.
I left that out of the picture.

Comment: Thanks for a well thought out, elaborate answer. I understand from the perspective of pointers in C. Can you quickly elaborate on your notation for addresses? I'm confused by the h and ch's.

Comment: @Eric: The `h` suffix means hex, and is common in DOS/Windows assembly as an alternative to `0x100c`.  `c` is a hex digit.  (Many DOS/Windows assemblers don't support `0xDEADBEEF`, only the less-readable-IMO `0DEADBEEFh`, so unfortunately this trailing-h style is common in x86 asm.)  NASM supports both ways, and other suffixes / prefixes for other number bases.  (base 2 is often useful).

Answer (score -2):

This is the answer to your question.

```
mov eax, [ebp+16] 
lea ebx, [ebp+12] 
mov eax, [ebx+4]
```

or

```
mov eax, [ebp+16]
mov ebx, ebp
add ebx, 12
mov eax, [ebx+4]
```

The former saves a few bytes of code, but they are functionally equivalent.

Comment: mmm... It's not clear why you use `mov eax, [ebp+16]` when you overwrite `eax` two/three instructions later without using it. Besides that, your code is just a silly way of writing `mov eax, [ebp+16]` which would access the 3rd (non standard, yet often provided) parameter of *main*, not `argv[1]`. This is not the answer to OP question.